# set ImageView's photo with bitmap using openGL

Tags: android, image, opengl-es, bitmap

I know that there are many questions like this but nothing helps me. So I have `bitmap` and I should set it like image on `ImageView`. Here is part of my code

```
Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize(); 
YuvImage yuvimage=new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, previewSize.width, previewSize.height, null);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, previewSize.width, previewSize.height), 80, baos);
byte[] jdata = baos.toByteArray();

// Convert to Bitmap
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata, 0, jdata.length);
m_VideCaptureBitmap.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

my `data` is byte array in what I have my image in bytes. So I need my app to work faster and that's why I need to use `openGl`. Can anybody give link or past a simple code , that I can use  for my app ?

Comment: Thanks for response :)
No it works , I need do the same thing using openGL

Comment: ok, there are som opengl demo in android sdk. gook luck.